# In safari option value not redirecting to the url. In chrome mozila and ie it is working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari

```
<select id="url">
   <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">MPEP November 2015 Revision, Click your selection</option> 
   <option value="http://google.com>google</option>
   <option value="http://facebook.com>facebook</option>
</select>

<script type = 'text/javascript'>
   document.getElementById("url").onchange = function() {
      if(this.selectedIndex!==0) {
         var win=window.open(this.value, '_blank');
         win.focus();
      }        
   };
</script>
```

This **script** and **html** tag is working in chrome, ie and mozila but **it is not working in Safari**, what is the problem with this script. I can check the code on mobile devices as well. on mobile devices also i face similar problem , it is not working in safari and working in other browsers.

Comment: Its a stupid question but have you checked `Popup Blocker`? Try adding `console.log` in your function and see if it logs. If yes, browser is blocking redirections